# My Visual Studio makes an .exe file instead of .dll

Tags: c#, visual-studio, powershell

I was following [this tutorial](https://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/net-development/using-c-to-create-powershell-cmdlets-the-basics/#fourth), but at step 5 I had to import a .dll file in PowerShell:

```
PS> Import-Module .\bin\Debug\PowerShellModuleInCSharp.dll
```

But my Visual Studio program only makes an .exe file. I tried importing the .exe file, but this gave an error

> Import-Module : The extension '.exe' is not a valid module extension. The supported module extensions are '.dll', '.ps1', '.psm1', '.psd1', '.cdxml' and '.xaml'. Correct the extension then try adding the file 'C:\users\wouter\documents\visual studio`.

So is this because I am making a Windows application instead of an console application in Visual Studio?

This is how my `Debug` folder looks like:

[image: Screenshot of debug folder content.]

Comment: Change your project type to class library. It's a setting in a drop down in the project properties screen.

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 This fixed the problem, thank you

Comment: @wouterdejong post what you learned as an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you weren't following that tutorial. Quoting that tutorial (emphasis mine):

> **Step 1: Create a Visual Studio project**
>
> Within your Visual Studio solution, you will house your cmdlets in a project, just as you would any other component you are building. For PowerShell, ***create a Class Library project*** so that once you have built the project, you have a DLL that comprises your PowerShell cmdlets.

The project you created was not a class library project. You appear to have created a Windows Forms Application project instead.

While it's possible to fix this, it involves more than simply changing the project type to "Class Library". The Windows Forms Application project template contains a lot of things you neither need nor should want. It contains references to assemblies you don't want. It contains a form. It contains program start-up code. All of that will remain if you simply change the project type, and you would need to get rid of it manually. It's easier to start over, taking care to follow the steps of the tutorial exactly.

Answer (score 2):

You need to change your project to be of type "Class Library" . For new projects its a matter of picking the "Class Library" template. For existing projects, there is a drop down list in the project properties screen that you can change to "Class Library" . Once you do that, you will need to recompile.

Comment: I agree with @hvd that you should really start over. But you *can* change to class library. I've not looked at that tutorial so I am not sure how involved everything is. If you can start over, you really should. And like hvd says, make sure to follow the tutorial *exactly* . Attention to detail is always important.

Answer (score 2):

Go to *Project* > *Properties* and change the *Output Type* in the dropdown shown below in red to *Class Library*:

[image]